# Using dd Through an Intermediate Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, dd

I'm interested in cloning one of my Windows drives to a new 2.5 inch SSD, but it's they're both 2.5 inch drives and I only have one SATA to USB connector.

Both are 500GB.

I have a 1TB usb hard drive I can use as an intermediate.

Will there be any issues cloning the Windows drive to the 1TB and then cloning the 1TB to the 500GB SSD?

I'm going to be using the KDE live USB at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to tackle this is to clone the original disk to a file on the intermediate drive, then clone that file to the new disk:

Assuming, that `/dev/sdX` is you SSD and `/dev/sdY` your USB intermediate (replace as necessary) with a file system, you would do something along the lines of

```
mount /dev/sdY /mnt
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/mnt/sdY.raw bs=1M
```

Then replace the SSD and

```
dd of=/dev/sdX if=/mnt/sdY.raw bs=1M
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct syntax? `of=/mnt/sdY.raw` seems a bit suspicious. What is the `mnt/sdY.raw` part? Is that a signal to dd? It seems like a folder path that does not exist on `/mnt` at first.

Comment: I am sure. `man dd` will inform you of the unusual syntax of `dd`

Comment: It is a **file** that does not exist on `/mnt` first, but then is created (containing a byte-per-byte copy of the SSD)